Counter output not synchronized to clk in vhdl in real fpga
I am trying to figure out why there is instable output of simple counter. I am using Sipeed Tang Primer 20k development board based on GW2A-LV18PG256C8/I7 FPGA. I created simple project, which uses clock divider to get output clock ~5.5 Mhz from input 27 Mhz global clock.
Top level design counter_tester.vhd looks like this:

counter_tester.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity counter_tester is
  port(
       CLK_IN_27MHZ : in STD_LOGIC;
       PROCESSOR_RST : in STD_LOGIC;
       BT656_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
       BT656_LLC_OUT : out STD_LOGIC
  );
end counter_tester;

architecture counter_tester of counter_tester is

---- Component declarations -----

component Gowin_CLKDIV
  port(
       hclkin : in STD_LOGIC;
       resetn : in STD_LOGIC;
       clkout : out STD_LOGIC
  );
end component;
component my_counter
  port(
       CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
       RST : in STD_LOGIC;
       Q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
  );
end component;

---- Signal declarations used on the diagram ----

signal NET672 : STD_LOGIC;
signal NET693 : STD_LOGIC;

begin

----  Component instantiations  ----

U1 : my_counter
  port map(
       CLK => NET672,
       RST => NET693,
       Q => BT656_OUT
  );

NET693 <= not(PROCESSOR_RST);

U4 : Gowin_CLKDIV
  port map(
       hclkin => CLK_IN_27MHZ,
       resetn => PROCESSOR_RST,
       clkout => NET672
  );


---- Terminal assignment ----

    -- Output\buffer terminals
    BT656_LLC_OUT <= NET672;


end counter_tester;

Here is code of counter itself:
my_counter.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity my_counter is
     port(
         CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
         RST : in STD_LOGIC;
         Q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
         );
end my_counter;


architecture my_counter of my_counter is
    signal s_Q_OUT: UNSIGNED (7 downto 0);
begin
    Q <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(s_Q_OUT);
   
    process( CLK )
    begin
        if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
            if (RST = '1') then
                s_Q_OUT <= (others => '0');
            else
                if(s_Q_OUT = x"FF") then
                    s_Q_OUT <= (others => '0');
                else
                    s_Q_OUT <= s_Q_OUT + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end my_counter;

I may also include code of Gowin's generated Clock divider module, but it's nothing interesting in it and it just works:
Gowin_CLKDIV.vhd
--Copyright (C)2014-2024 Gowin Semiconductor Corporation.
--All rights reserved.
--File Title: IP file
--Tool Version: V1.9.9.02
--Part Number: GW2A-LV18PG256C8/I7
--Device: GW2A-18
--Created Time: Sun Jul 21 23:14:25 2024

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Gowin_CLKDIV is
    port (
        clkout: out std_logic;
        hclkin: in std_logic;
        resetn: in std_logic
    );
end Gowin_CLKDIV;

architecture Behavioral of Gowin_CLKDIV is

    signal gw_gnd: std_logic;

    --component declaration
    component CLKDIV
        generic (
            GSREN: STRING := "false";
            DIV_MODE : STRING := "2"
        );
        port (
            CLKOUT: out std_logic;
            HCLKIN: in std_logic;
            RESETN: in std_logic;
            CALIB: in std_logic
        );
    end component;

begin
    gw_gnd <= '0';

    clkdiv_inst: CLKDIV
        generic map (
            GSREN => "false",
            DIV_MODE => "5"
        )
        port map (
            CLKOUT => clkout,
            HCLKIN => hclkin,
            RESETN => resetn,
            CALIB => gw_gnd
        );

end Behavioral; --Gowin_CLKDIV

All outputs except one pin in FPGA are configured to use same IO bank:

I connected logic analyzer which samples on 100 Mhz to output pins. First, this is overall image that we get on DSLogic analyzer. As we can see, counter in general works, bits are incremented:

Now let's zoom in

Here we see that clock frequency is only ~5 Mhz. In decoder settings I choose to decode data on rising edge of clock BT656_LLC_OUT.
But counter quite often misses with output values. Some of data lanes change after 20 ns of clock rising edge. I placed two markers, and in right bottom we can see calculated time difference.
I added colors to each data lane and zoomed it to demonstrate more clearly:

Line D5 changes 0 -> 1 same time as BT656_LLC_OUT changes 0 -> 1
But all other lines change 0 -> 1 only after 20 ns! I find it nonsense. This counter produces too much wrong values on rising edges of clock. Anyone knows what it could be the reason? I am trying to find solution for days...
Here how my dev board is connected with logic analyzer. Board to which probes are connected, is not connected by FFC to other board (ADV7391 encoder)

I also have set timing constraints in Gowin EDA:
fpga_project_4.sdc
create_clock -name CLK_IN_27MHZ -period 37.037 -waveform {0 18.518} [get_ports {CLK_IN_27MHZ}] -add
Would be thankful for any help!
I also tried to move output assignment inside process under rising_edge(clk) but result was same. Just registers needed increase in GowinEDA
UPD: Also after creation this topic, I had an idea about adding 8-bit D-register on output which will work on inverted clock - on falling edge. Like this:

So I added it and tested with real FPGA. And it was just WOW! No wrong numbers in output, just perfect counter from some digital electronics university book!
And is it normal practice in FPGA design to add additional output register with inverted clk to outputs?

You don't appear to present a programming question here. Asynchronous sampling with your logic analyzer will give you +/- 1 sample uncertainty. Can measuring between edges of BT656_LLC_OUT (the clock with +/- 1 sample uncertainty) and a counter out (with +/- 1 sample uncertainty) give you two sample times difference?

I would expect propagation in the range of 0 to 2 sample cycles, nothing wrong here.

Unrelated question, what's the video dac module in the bottom right corner?

Bottom right is video ADC ADV7180 (black) - bought module on aliexpress. For video DAC I use ADV7391 (green). Also bought on aliexpress

On real hardware, you will never have multiple outputs change at exactly the same point in time. This is true especially if you measure different value changes, from 0 to 1, and from 1 to 0, because of different hardware behavior when digitalizing the actual analog voltages.
This is reality, electronics and physics.
Even if you add a register as you did, you will have timing differences.
Therefore you have to live with "glitches" of invalid values after the triggering clock edge. There is no way to avoid them.

In the word "after" is already the reason, why it is not common practice to add output registers with inverted clocks. The common practice is to use a synchronous design with one clock.
The next stage of your logic will take the output of the current stage with the next clock edge. The different propagation delays do not matter, as the current clock edge is before the level changes. The next stage saw the former values.
Just make sure that your clock is not too fast to meet the setup times of the next stage. BTW, with your inserted register you cut this maximum frequency to 50% because this register needs stable levels after 50% of the clock cycle. However, your design seems to be quite slow.

Your observations are based on single measurements with a low sample rate.
The sample clock is unrelated to the design's clock. When a sample is taken about the same time a signal changes, it can randomly be the old or the new level. You always have a jitter of one sample cycle on each single signal.
This could be the scenario for your measurement:
                    ____________________
Actual clock   ____/    |     |     |
                  |     |_____|_____|___
Actual D5      ___|____/|     |     |
               ___|_____|_____|     |
Actual D4         |     |     |\____|___
                  |     |     |     |
Sample trigger    X     X     X     X
                         _______________
Sampled clock  _________/
                         _______________
Sampled D5     _________/
               _____________________
Sampled D4                          \___


Raise the sample rate, and you will find that the interval becomes shorter.
Take multiple measurements, and you find find different delays.

And you will find that your register has these glitches, too.

Note: This is a non-programming issue. However, the questioner asks about common practice in VHDL design to avoid the observed effect, which is programming. Therefore I think this question is on-topic here.

Yes, later I found that there is similar site as stackoverflow, but for electronics design, so here may be not best place for such question. I also order logic analyzer with 500 Mhz sampling frequency. Hope when it arrives, I will be able to see precisely signal changes.
So it's not common practice to add registers with inverted clock on output. I suspected it!

@Alex Using such "synchronizing attempts" simply make no sense and just bloat the design.

Well, that's the result of my current level of knowledge in fpga, still learning with real ones
